# "Access is denied" message after logging in to windows 2012 r2 via remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

I installed the Remote Desktop Session Host server role on a windows 2012 r2 machine. After that, I rebooted the VM and now when I try to log in via remote desktop, after a little while in the log in process, I get an "Access is denied" yellow message with an OK button below. I was able to log in before that.

Any idea on how I can fix this? I am local admin on the server but I cannot launch remotely the Server Manager. I was able to run the Computer Management console.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to log on locally via the console, rather than remotely via RDP? Windows does differentiate depending on this.

Comment: Could you please be more specific, how do I connect via the console? I was able to connect via the Computer Management console. Thanks

Comment: Try logging on to it physically (monitor, keyboard, and mouse) or, if possible, remotely via something like out-of-band management, Virtual Machine console, LogMeIn, TeamViewer, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot proceed with any of these options. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is the server connected to an AD DS domain? If so, can you log on using a domain administrator account?

Comment: I am not a domain admin but I asked the help of someone with higher access level than me. Yes, the computer belongs a domain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63879/discussion-between-mythofechelon-and-costa).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it just got bumped up to the home page.

If you find yourself locked out of a Remote Desktop server, just run `mstsc.exe /admin`. This will log you in to the console session, bypassing all RDS licensing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by uninstalling the Remote Desktop Session Host feature via powershell commands. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find the real cause of this issue.